# Does keepattributes without any arguments in ProGuard assume all arguments?

Tags: java, proguard

Just a quick question, since the documentation is unclear on the matter. If you don't specify arguments for -keepattributes in ProGuard, will it keep all attributes, no attributes, or some standard attributes?

Thanks!
-Vic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-keepattributes without arguments keeps all attributes. It's a bit unusual maybe, since it could include unimportant or even unknown attributes. Attributes that are not known to ProGuard might become invalid if they require updating in some processing step.